# My Userform keep shrinking after every use

Tags: excel, vba

Almost every time I use my user form, it shrinks, and after a few times it gets too small to see and I have to go back into the forms on my project and drag it until the size is large again. Is this a result of my code, or is there something that I can do to fix this?

```
Option Explicit

' called on click of "OK" button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MyFile = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub

' called on click of "Cancel" button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Stopped = True
    Unload Me
End Sub

' loads the combo box with the names of all available workbooks
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            If wkb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
                .AddItem wkb.Name
            End If
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any code anywhere that assigns the form's `Height` and/or `Width`?

Comment: FWIW the "names of all available workbooks" comment is lying... it's "all workbooks except the one that's currently active" - best move that code to some `Private Sub GetInactiveWorkbookNames()`, removes the need for a potentially confusing comment ;-)  ..similarly, renaming the buttons `OkButton` and `CancelButton` removes the need for comments explaining what `CommandButton1` and `CommandButton2` are

Comment: No, I don't have any code that assigns the forms height/width, and this is all of the code that is affecting the UserForm. Thank you for the tip on the inactive workbooks I will add that.

Comment: I guess you could work around the issue (no idea how that incremental shrinking is possible) by explicitly setting the `Height` and `Width` to constant values in the `Initialize` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a reason for this to happen, especially without any code anywhere tweaking the `Height` and `Width` of the form, and with the form `Unload`-ing itself every time it's shown, even if you're `Show`-ing the form's *default instance* it **should** still be initialized with the design-time values.

You could try forcing a size explicitly in that initialize handler:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Height = 480
    Me.Width = 600
    InitializeComponents
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeComponents()
    PopulateAvailableInactiveWorkbooks
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateAvailableInactiveWorkbooks()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    With Me.ComboBox1
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            If wkb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
                .AddItem wkb.Name
            End If
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue, you may like to check;
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/userforms-shrink-on-successive-openings-of-an-excel-file.1078705/
For me, adding the following to the userform code at least kept the display right.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With frm40_Overview1
        Height = 600
        Width = 800
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```